504 gateway timeout. expressjs, laravel lumen and vue
I have a big problem with my microservices marketplace, that always return "504 gateway timeout".
I use frontend with Vue Quasar, backend with Laravel Lumen 10 and API gateway with Express.js Node 20.17, deploying apps in Kubernetes and monitoring the service with KubeSphere.
I have several repo services for payment, notification and marketplace.
The problem always in Laravel services that return this:

93 upstream timed out (110: Operation timed out) while reading response header from upstream.

Has anyone here experience to fix it?
I even added 20 pods on marketplace service, 10 pods on payment and 6 pods on notification, but the error still appears.
I already tried to add fastcgi dan nginx timeout to 600s, but the error is still there.
I hope the service can process the request smoothly, with the tech stack I use right now.
